# regex to replace string with params

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, preg-replace

Please help me to create regex for replace a string like: 
 
**/technic/k-700/?type=repair** 
to a string like 
**/repair/k-700/**

Instead of **k-700** can be any another combination (between **/** ) and instead of **repair** can be only **kit**.
I need pattern and replacement, please. It's so hard for me.
My result not working for *Wordpress*:

```
$pattern = '/technic/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?type=$matches[1]';
$replacement = '/?/([0-9a-z-]+)/';
```

Comment: would you like to get rid of *everything* including and after the `?` ?

Comment: @AlexAndrei I think the "repair" from query string becomes the first segment of the new URL and one that was first before isn't used.

Comment: thanks @mishu, missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$test = preg_replace(
    '~/\w+/([\w-]+)/\?type=(\w+)~i',
    '/$2/$1/',
    '/technic/k-700/?type=repair'
);
var_dump($test);
```

The result will be:

```
string(14) "/repair/k-700/"
```

Comment: So I get it `RewriteRule ^/$2/$1/ /~/\w+/([\w-]+)/\?type=(\w+)~i [QSA,L]` in my htaccess-file?

Comment: No.. you didn't specified the question is related to mod-rewrite.. it is just for php

Comment: @MateiMihai it is in the tags..., but yes, web6ak, you could explicit in the question: all the answers ignore RewriteRule!

Comment: @MateiMihai ok, no problem. It was another question. Your decision is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex, you can do it simply by using `explode()`:

```
$str = '/technic/k-700/?type=repair';
$first = explode('/', explode('?', $str)[0]);
$second = explode('=', explode('?', $str)[1]);
$first[1] = $second[1];
echo $new = implode("/",$first);

//output: /repair/k-700/
```

Comment: The result must be `/repair/k-700/`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness or if you need to access the url parts later.
Here's a solution using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$str = '/technic/k-700/?type=repair';

$url = parse_url($str);

$bits = explode('/',trim($url['path'],'/'));

parse_str($url['query']);

print '/' . $type . '/' . $bits[1] . '/' ;
```

Which will output

```
/repair/k-700/
```