# Transform Regex to RewriteRule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A few minutes ago I asked a question and received a very good response. It works.  [(This is it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627926/regex-to-replace-string-with-params). I added it to my PHP scripts. Now I need to complete my site with another question like that but little characterized. I need to get rewrite rule from that regex (it's different problem, not my previous).
I need to rewrite link like:

```
http://my_site.com/technic/k-700/?type=repair
```

to link like:

```
http://my_site.com/repair/k-700/
```

Instead of **k-700** can be any another combination (between **/** ) and instead of **repair** can be only **kit**.
Now I need rewrite rule for .htaccess file. Please.
My result is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/].)/k-700/$ /technic/k-700/?type=$1 [L]
```

I can't avoid that **k-700** :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct and this is going in your root .htaccess, then try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(repair|kit)/([^/]+)/?$ technic/$2/?type=$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** Re-read your description. a little ambiguity with the `repair` vs `kit` value and whether substitution should always have `k-700`. So here are a few more examples catering to those possibilities:

```
RewriteRule ^(repair|kit)/([^/]+)/?$ technic/k-700/?type=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(kit)/([^/]+)/?$ technic/k-700/?type=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(kit)/([^/]+)/?$ technic/$2/?type=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so musch. The first variant is the best. Also the last variant I will use later.